# JS - create binary mask based on convex hull

Tags: javascript, convex-hull

I have a convex hull outline generated by https://github.com/AndriiHeonia/hull

I have a number of points (about 100K) I need to test to see if they are within the hull. I am not wanting to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/point-in-polygon as it appears it will have to loop through the entire hull for every single point which I would imagine is very inefficient.

How can I create a binary mask or greyscale mask (0 for outside, 255 for inside hull) based on this hull that I can then reference later on to test if points are inside or outside the hull?

Thanks!